# How do I convert Gremlin-Console-Code in Java-Code?

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I really like Gremlin but I think it's sometimes really hard to convert the Code of the Console to Java-Code
For Example this:

```
g.E().project('EDGE','IN','OUT','PROP')
     .by(id())
     .by(inV().union(id()).fold())
     .by(outV().union(id()).fold())
     .by(properties().fold())
```

Works fine in the Console but not in Java. Can someone help me with this code or maybe give me a good addvice for the future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gremlin Console automatically has a host of static imports in place so that you can save keystrokes and make Gremlin look less verbose. When you do:

```
g.E().project('EDGE','IN','OUT','PROP')
     .by(id())
     .by(inV().union(id()).fold())
     .by(outV().union(id()).fold())
     .by(properties().fold())
```

What you're really doing is:

```
g.E().project('EDGE','IN','OUT','PROP')
     .by(__.id())
     .by(__.inV().union(__.id()).fold())
     .by(__.outV().union(__.id()).fold())
     .by(__.properties().fold())
```

In your Java application you merely need to include an `import` statement like:

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.*;
```

and the original syntax from the Groovy console will paste perfectly into a Java application. Or if you prefer the more verbose syntax use a standard `import` of the `__` class and then explicitly use that to spawn your child traversals as demonstrated in teh second example above. Please see the full list of suggested imports in the [Reference Documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#java-imports).

Comment: note that when possible you should use `T.id` or just `id` (again - static import), rather than `id()` step - https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#steps-instead-of-tokens